# PHP - Can I import rules from another file or DB into .htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have multiple domains running on the same code and the same directory, sharing the same .htaccess file also. I want to make those domains use separate redirect rules either from db or another file. So my question is that can I import rules from another file or DB into .htaccess file? 
Is it possible or not, if yes then how?
Prior thanks to any help...

Comment: Use a router and set them up in PHP instead. htaccess can't read other files or do any database queries. If you really want to set it all up in htaccess, then you need to manually build that htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to write the information from the database to the `.htaccess` file. It means you have to regenerate it yourself. You can read more about the format here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html

You can do a similar thing using the HTTP based authentication: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication and store this information in cookies (and session). A very simple example can be found in this gist: https://gist.github.com/rchrd2/c94eb4701da57ce9a0ad4d2b00794131

Comment: What does the question have to do with http authentication?

Comment: he wants some dynamical authentication so I gave another way to solve the problem

Comment: There's no mention of authentication in the question. The OP is asking about dynamically importing redirect/rewrite rules, which is a totally different thing.